# Counter is not working - implementing a like button inside php

Tags: javascript, php, html, echo

I am trying to implement like button when after clicked it should increment the number of likes but i am trying to implement inside the php code but it is not working and i am not able to figure out what is the problem here?

```html
<html>
<script>
$(".like_button button").on("click", function() {
  var $count = $(this).parent().find('.count');
  $count.html($count.html() * 1 + 1);
});
</script>
<?php
   echo '<div class="like_button">
  <button>Like</button>
  <span class="count">0</span>
</div>';
?>
</html>
```

why this code is not working?

Comment: Why are you using PHP tags at all?  You're not actually using any PHP (besides the echo, which really serves no purpose). And if this is really all the code you have, then you're not loading the jQuery library anywhere.

Comment: Are there errors in your browser's console?

Comment: No errors but the increment is not working. This is a part of bigger code where i need to use html inside php code.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're selecting your button before it exists. Put `$(".like_button button")` *after* the button :

```
<?php
   echo '<div class="like_button">
  <button>Like</button>
  <span class="count">0</span>
</div>';
?>

<script>
    $(".like_button button").on("click", function() {
        var $count = $(this).parent().find('.count');
         $count.html($count.html() * 1 + 1);
    });
</script>
```

**Edit :**

Following up with your comments, you haven't included jQuery but you're trying to use it (`$`). Then the solution is simple : include jQuery. And *open your console*.

**Working snippet :**

```js
$(".like_button button").on("click", function() {
  var $count = $(this).parent().find('.count');
  $count.html($count.html() * 1 + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="like_button">
  <button>Like</button>
  <span class="count">0</span>
</div>
<div class="like_button">
  <button>Like</button>
  <span class="count">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe it would also work with event delegation, `$(".like_button").on("click", "button", function() {`

Comment: That's wrong. $(...) is jQuery and runs on the client (browser). PHP runs on the server.

Comment: @Andy Yes, it also would. If it still doesn't work, then your problem is elsewhere. Did you include jQuery? What does your console say? Any error?

Comment: @RobSky So? PHP will render the button, won't it?

Comment: how to rectify this?

Comment: rectify "this" what?

Comment: no i have included only this part of the code which i have put here in the forum.

Comment: no jquery, do i have to include jquery also? and what in the jquery i shound include?

Comment: Well, of course... `$` is jQuery, if you don't include it, it can't work. _Open. Your. Console._ It's telling you all this.

Comment: @MiteshKhadgi : Jeremy is referring to your developer console. If you are using Google Chrome, then you can access this by hitting *Control-Shift-J*. There's a tab in here named *Console*. You might see an error here that can help you figure out what to try next.

Comment: After including the google jquery, still it is not working.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. I have edited my answer and added a little snippet, and it works. It's just about clicking a button, it's not rocket science. BTW, `the google jquery` doesn't really mean anything. jQuery isn't made by Google. And _did you open your console?_